# How can objects access attributes of the class in which they are contained?

Tags: c++, oop

Let's imagine I have a code that simulate the working of a country education system. This country contain `Cities`, which contain `Schools`, which contain `Classes`, which contain `Students`. I use a global singleton called `CountryInformation` that all classes (`City`, `School`, `Class` and `Students`) are accessing.

I would like to expand my code to consider several countries. Each country need their own `CountryInformation`, therefore `CountryInformation` is not a singleton anymore. I would like that each elements contained in a given `Country` can access to the `countryInformation` associated to their country. How can I do that?

A simplified version of the problem is to consider that below is my current code

```
int info = 3;

class City
{
public:
  void foo(){std::cout << info << std::endl;}
};

class Country
{
public:   
  City city;
  void callFoo(){this->city.foo();}
};

int main()
{
  Country C;
  C.callFoo();
}
```

and I would now like to have something like

```
class City
{
public:
  void foo(){std::cout << info << std::endl;}
};

class Country
{
public:   
  City city;
  int info;
  void callFoo(){this->city.foo();}
  Country(int i):info(i){}
};

int main()
{
  std::vector<Country> countries;
  Country C1(0);
  Country C2(0);
  countries.push_back(C1);
  countries.push_back(C2);
  countries[0].callFoo();
  countries[1].callFoo();
}
```

but the above code does not compile as the City object in a given Country does not have access to the attribute of the Country object.

I have been considering friendship and nested classes but I fail to wrap my head around how to give this access.

**EDIT**

I would like to avoid the need of every `City`, `School` and `Student` to carry a pointer around. A pointer is typically 4 to 8 bytes and a `Student`is typically 8 bytes. So, doing so would double the RAM need.

Comment: Pass the "this" pointer of the country object to the constructor of City so that City can access the pieces of Country.  If the pieces are private you will need to make City a "friend"

Comment: Maybe a common base class for `city` and `country` which has `int info` as member variable.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah Are you suggesting that every `City`, every `School` and esp. every `Student` should carry a pointer to the Country in which it is contained? That would represent a fair amount of extra RAM as every student is typically only 8 bytes.

Comment: Even if you do something completely weird and use inheritance so City is a subclass of Country and School is a subclass of City, etc then you can access the super class protected data but you still have the vtable pointer so you are no better off.  You either need a reference, the this pointer or a vtable pointer.  Unless you can change your design so that you don't need to access info upwards.

Answer (score 0):

Your classes are not "nested;" one class simply has the other classes as members. `City` objects can only communicate with `Country` objects via the public API. However, actual nested classes, or inner classes, *are* able to access the private variables of the outer class:

```
class Country
{
  class City
  {
  public:
    City(Country& c) : country(c) {}
    void foo() {
      country.info = 1;
    }
  private:
    Country& country;
  };
  int info;
};
```

Either way, you will have to explicitly pass the `Country` object to the `City` object.